# How to trigger google doc script with button or by editting it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to summarize info sent by a form (to make purchase requests) on a google doc with a way to approve the request or not from the google doc and retrieve the information in a Google Apps Script function.

The problem is that on Google Document the trigger onEdit doesn't exist.

Is there a way to create one ?
Or simply add a button to validate the request that would call a function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to add a button that calls an Apps Script function on a Google Documents document is by creating a dialog or sidebar. This is done by using the HTML Service. For further details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Comment: That's what i've done finally, and it worked, thanks.